# How do you add a "Back button" on the iPad's SplitViewController popover Navigation bar?

Tags: ipad

How do you add the Navigation items on the popover (left pane) of the iPad's splitview?  This is where the mailboxes/inbox/drafts part of the navigation is in the iPad's builtin email application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `UISplitViewController`’s “master” pane a `UINavigationController`, then just push `UIViewController`s on it that have `navigationItem`s.

Here’s a sample setup:

```
UIViewController *masterController = [[MyCustomMasterController alloc] init…];
[[masterController navigationItem] setTitle:@"Root"];

UINavigationController *navController =
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootController:masterController];

UIViewController *detailController [[MyCustomDetailController alloc] init…];

UISplitViewController *splitView = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
[splitView setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController,
                                                        detailController,
                                                        nil]];
```

And then later on:

```
UIViewController *subController = [[MyCustomSubController alloc] init…];
[[masterController navigationController] pushViewController:subController
                                                   animated:YES];
```

Pushing a new `UIViewController` to the `UINavigationController`’s stack will cause a back button titled “Root” to appear for the `MyCustomMasterController` view.